# How to update firmware of my iPod Touch in Ubuntu?

Tags: itunes, ubuntu-10.04, ipod-touch, firmware

As far as I know iTunes doesn't support Linux OS, though it is very strange. I need to update a firmware of my iPod Touch and don't know how to do that.

Could anybody help me to solve this problem please?

**Update 1**

I know that it is possible to install Windows in VirtualBox and use it right from the Ubuntu. But should I buy Windows (for some 100Euro) ONLY to update firmware of my iPod? Isn't it devil  Apple, that makes us to buy things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a virtualization software like VirtualBox and install Windows. It's not possible using Wine, I don't think Wine would be able to gain access to the iPod as a "device".

If you're using VirtualBox, do remember to use the [PUEL version](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox_PUEL), rather than the OSE version since the OSE version doesn't have USB support and cannot pass-through  USB devices to the guest.

Comment: You are right Sathya. But does it make a sense to buy Windows only for  updating firmware of my iPod???

Comment: @Bakthtiyor: Unfortunately that doesn't make any sense. How about updating the firmware at a friend's place ?

Comment: Hmmm... I think the only solution is this. So, probably I will use my friend's computer for that. APPLE is really EVIL!!!!